# Re-Adding Bullet & Italics to CkEditor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor

I have inherited an MVC3 C# .Net Web App which uses CkEditor.  The ability to insert bold text and italicized text has been removed from the CkEditor boxes by another developer (who is no longer here).  How can I re-add the Bold & Italics functionality back into CkEditor?

Comment: Download the CKEditor unaltered sample code and do a comparison.

Comment: @Shyju...Yeah...that resulted in tons of diffs.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  Attributes of the .toolbar config property had been removed.  I.e.

```
    toolbar: [
            { name: 'insert', items: ['Image'] },
            { name: 'tools', items: ['Maximize'] },
        ],
```

I modified to:

```
    toolbar: [
            { name: 'insert', items: ['Image'] },
            { name: 'tools', items: ['Maximize'] },
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'], ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList']
        ],
```

Here's the Url that helped me: [CkEditor Config Stuff](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/questions/6330/using-ckeditor-in-a-new-plugin)